# 'On click' not working for some elements on iOS cordova

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

In cordova for the iOS the following works for button and anchor elements (only if href is set):

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.submit-question', function() 
        console.log("Test");
    });
```

even though the elements aren't added initially - only after a while.

But the following doesn't work on iOS (but does on Android)

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'h1', function() {
        console.log("Test 2");
    });
```

Even when the h1 element is there from the start (but it won't be ultimately). When `$('h1').click()` is done in the Safari console it works but clicking it on the device won't work.

Comment: Try to add `tap` and `touch` events along with `click`..

Comment: I am using jQuery and jQueryUI - I get an error for `$('h1').tap()` and `$('h1').touch()` so perhaps I don't have the right libraries.

Comment: I'm using an anchor element with `href="javascript:;"` and styled to look like the h1 now and it works

Comment: I meant something like  `$('body').on('click tap touchstart', 'h1',`

Answer (score 2):

hope this snippet below works. I just had the same problem and this fixed it.

```
$(function(){
    $(document.body).on('click tap touchstart', 'h1', function(){
        console.log("Test 2");
    })
})
```